# Image being cut off with onclick rotation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can someone help me figure out what I am missing here?

I've inserted a random photo from Wiki that is similar in size to some of the types of images that I would need this to work with.  The images will be of varying sizes, I just need them to always be viewable within the browser once rotated, regardless of the image size. Basically any time I rotate the image part of the image gets pushed outside the viewable area of the browser window.  It works exactly the way I need it to work, with the exception of the partial overflow.

What do I need to add to fix this?

Thanks,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    img {
      width: auto;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <img id="rotater" onclick="rotate(this)" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/6c/Us_flag_large_38_stars.png" style="transform: rotate(0deg)">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    let rotateAngle = 90;


    function rotate(image) {
      image.setAttribute("style", "transform: rotate(" + rotateAngle + "deg)");
      rotateAngle = rotateAngle + 90;
    }
  </script>

  <div class="as-console-wrapper">
    <div class="as-console"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your image has more width than your height and is at the top of the page. Rotation keeping center fixed means some part of your image will move out of the page. (width/2)>(height/2) by quite a lot. When you rotate, **imagine** height becomes width and vice-versa.  Now since the position is still the same, but height has increased some of the image will overflow right? Here is a fixed demo if you move your image a bit low(margin-top) and reduce the width. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tusharshahi/pen/RwVWdgP) Does this help you?

Comment: Also : Width auto in your case means image will take as much width as its parent(body). Do you really want such a big image?

Comment: @ikiK CSS [rotate transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate()) and rotate CSS property are different. OP is using transform, it is very well supported.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply. This script would exist on a page with only the image - nothing else. Our users review applications in which they have to click on various links (supporting documents) which open in a new window with only a .jpg or .png inside. They could vary in size from a business card to an 8.5x11 piece of paper. So the idea is that the user can resize the browser window and the image will resize with the window. 

Is there a way to keep the image in its native size and still accomplish this?

Comment: Ok. I have updated this [codepen](https://codepen.io/tusharshahi/pen/RwVWdgP). Keeping width as you would want, I am just pushing the image down at our required angle, so the centre of the image is shifted. If your page is long enough to accommodate this should work right?

Comment: Thank you, your code works perfectly! You’re awesome. Unfortunately, I’ve been told it will take a year + to introduce any changes to production (smh, I know). So I’m back to the drawing board. Trying to find a way to maybe add a custom context menu to IE in registry that I can configure on client side machines that will give users the ability to right click on an image and rotate it that way. Not even sure if that’s possible.

Comment: Maybe a right click and “Send to Windows Photo Viewer” might work, where the user can rotate the image easily there and close it when done. Will have to look into that.

Comment: Aha. Ok. For the sake of this question I will post an answer so if anyone arrives here they can use this. Please mark it as accepted, if this helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image has more width than your height and is at the top of the page. Rotation keeping center fixed means some part of your image will move out of the page. (width/2)>(height/2) by quite a lot. When you rotate, imagine height becomes width and vice-versa.

Also: Width auto in your case means image will take as much width as its parent(body).

Keeping width as you would want, I am just pushing the image down at our required angle, so the centre of the image is shifted.

```js
    let rotateAngle = 90;


    function rotate(image) {
      image.setAttribute("style", "transform: rotate(" + rotateAngle + "deg)");
      rotateAngle = rotateAngle + 90;
      if(rotateAngle%180==0){
        image.classList.add('pushDown');
      }
      else{
   image.classList.remove('pushDown');     
      }
    }
```

```css
  img {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
     height: auto;

    }

.pushDown{
  margin-top: 25%;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
  <img id="rotater" onclick="rotate(this)" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/6c/Us_flag_large_38_stars.png" style="transform: rotate(0deg)">

  <div class="as-console-wrapper">
    <div class="as-console"></div>
  </div>
```